# Laptop keyboard not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, lenovo

My laptop keyboard is not working, I have Ubunutu 18.04 installed. Only keys working are F1-F12 , ESC, TAB and Screenshot shortcut (s).

The laptop is a Lenovo T440s Core i7

I have tried the following and still the keyboard is not working
1. Reinstalling input drivers using:  sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
2. Ubuntu reinstallation
3. Ctrl + Alt + F3
4. Upadatng the system using sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
5. Updating input driver in recovery mode 
6. Typing Assist and Bouncing keys are both off in Universal Access settings 
7. Also tried sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration but couldn\t find my keyboard 
8. Tried Live CD but key

Even when i go to bio settings keyboard is not working. However, the keypad is working

What else can i do, thinking of switching to windows to see if problem persists

Comment: Have you ruled out the possibility of hardware failure? Try plugging in a USB keyboard to see if that works. I have heard of keyboards with dead keys. If your keyboard is not working in BIOS, then it's not strictly OS related.